# in Bash, how to not include extra arguments in an alias?

Tags: bash, alias, ftp, echo

I am trying to do something like

```
alias ftp='echo do not use ftp. Use sftp instead.'
```

just so that `ftp` will not be accidentally used.  But I noticed that

```
ftp abcd.com
```

will cause the command to echo

```
do not use ftp. Use sftp instead. abcd.com
```

because the `abcd.com` is taken to be an argument for `echo`.

Is there a way to make Bash not add `abcd.com` to the substitution, or make `echo` not take it as extra arguments?  (Is there a solution for each approach?)

I supposed I could make it

```
alias ftp='sftp'
```

but I just want to make the command stop all together to remind myself not to use `ftp`.

Comment: Mostly you can prohibit `ftp` in different way, but if you'd like to do so - use `printf` instead of `echo` : `printf "Do not use ftp. Use sftp instead.\n\c"`

Comment: Add the `echo` to the `sftp` alias? i.e. `alias ftp='echo "Do not use ftp"; sftp'`. You'll get the reminder, while also being forced to use `sftp`.

Comment: @JoshJolly I wanted to make the command to stop all together instead of letting it to "sail through" just so that I will be constantly reminded of not to use `ftp`

Comment: Note that aliases are extremely simple; they are *nothing more* than simple string substitution (with the additional limitations that (1) the substitution only happens at the beginning of the command string, and (2) it is non-recursive). There is no way to "configure" how an alias works beyond the definition of the alias itself.

Comment: Er...sorry, aliases *are* recursive. Not sure what I was thinking.

Answer (score 19):

When you define an alias, the command you set is run instead of the one you wrote. This means that when you run `ftp abc.com`, what is actually executed is

```
echo do not use ftp. Use sftp instead abc.com
```

A simple solution is to use a function instead of an alias:

```
ftp(){ echo 'do not use ftp. Use sftp instead'; }
```

Alternatively, you could use `printf` as suggested by Costas:

```
alias ftp="printf 'do not use ftp. Use sftp instead\n'"
```

Answer (score 17):

```
alias ftp='echo do not use ftp. Use sftp instead. # '
```

Comment: +1. Yet somehow this reminds me of SQL injections :') Sweet trick.

Answer (score 10):

Just put a space and the comment character `#` at the end of the alias string:

```
alias ftp='echo do not use ftp. Use sftp instead. #'
ftp abcd.com
do not use ftp. Use sftp instead.
```

This will cause the parameters to be treated as a comment. Just do not forget to add a space before `#` otherwise it will not be interpreted as a separate token after the alias expansion.